# If I make a Movie clip ".visible" does it still run in the background AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3, flashdevelop, visible

I had a Menu `MovieClip` with `tweens` running all the time and when the user clicks to start the game and when they do i add `menu.visible = true;` does this stop the menu from running in the background or does it just make it invisible and it will continue to run in the background and decrease performance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All instances of `MovieClip` in memory (that is there are references to them or they haven't been collected  by `GC` yet) are playing and consume some processor time for firing `EnterFrame` event or executing frame scripts. But it's still matter to set `visible=false` or remove them from `stage` to prevent their rendering, that can lead to consume even more resources.

And small bonus, I use this utility method that stops all animations before removing them from the `display list`, hope it helps:

```
/**
 * Stops all animations in the MovieClip and all its chilrend recursivly
 *
 * @param   target
 * @param   self stop animation in target or not
 * @param   isGoToAndStopFirstFrame move all clips to the first frame
 *
 */
public static function stopAll(target:DisplayObject, self:Boolean = true, isGoToAndStopFirstFrame:Boolean = false):void
{
    if (!target)
        return;

    var t:int = getTimer();
    var targetMovieClip:MovieClip = (target as MovieClip);
    if (self && targetMovieClip)
    {
        if(isGoToAndStopFirstFrame)
        {
            targetMovieClip.gotoAndStop(1);
        }else
        {
            targetMovieClip.stop();
        }
    }

    //stops all children in DisplayObjectContainer
    var targetContainer:DisplayObjectContainer = (target as DisplayObjectContainer);
    if(targetContainer)
    {
        for (var i:int=0; i<targetContainer.numChildren; i++)
        {
            var child:DisplayObject = targetContainer.getChildAt(i);
            if (child)
            {
                stopAll(child, true, isGoToAndStopFirstFrame);
            }
        }
    }

    // stops all states in SimpleButton
    var targetSimpleButton:SimpleButton = (target as SimpleButton);
    if(targetSimpleButton)
    {
        stopAll(targetSimpleButton.overState, true, isGoToAndStopFirstFrame);
        stopAll(targetSimpleButton.upState, true, isGoToAndStopFirstFrame);
        stopAll(targetSimpleButton.downState, true, isGoToAndStopFirstFrame);
        stopAll(targetSimpleButton.hitTestState, true, isGoToAndStopFirstFrame);
    }

    return;
}
```

Comment: This is awesome. Thanks for all the info I had no idea by removing any Movie clip it would still consume resource. Not sure how Garbage Collection works yet or how to implement it. But this seems like a start. So all i would need to do is add this inside my endGame class? Or would I be initiating it in my main Engine class? I'm not sure what might be causing it but i know for sure i have a memory leak because my memory seems to increase at a constant pace and after a minute it just becomes sluggish.

Comment: it's an utility method for complex animations with nested timelines. If you have only single-timeline animations (without nested timelines) you can just call _mc.stop()_ before removing it or setting _visible=false_

Comment: you are welcome, feel free to mark the question as answered )

Comment: Sorry about that almost forgot haha